# Why "magnetic properties"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Why do we talk about a material or metal having magnetic properties (as opposed to having a magnetic property)?

Comment: Do you have an example quote or reference to support this? Context helps.

Comment: How do you know it's one?

Comment: How do I delete my question? This is rather embarrassing. I was mixing the common usage of an object either being attracted to magnets or not, with the physical concept of magnetism.  Is it too late to go back?

Comment: @By137: Take it easy, dude. If you really want your question to be deleted, flag it and write *Please delete as self delete wont work*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"there is only one property".

This is not the case; a material will have several magnetic properties including [saturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_%28magnetic%29), [permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29) and [magnetic moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) (see [here](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/mu/) for more), which is why the plural is used, as it would also be used in the case of *thermal properties* or *electrical properties*.

Answer (score 1):

The reference here is not to the property of being magnetic as such, but to the quality of possessing/ exhibiting magnetic properties.

There's no reason why there should be only a single magnetic property.

Every magnetic object exhibits a set of certain properties.

Furthermore, when we do refer to the magnetic nature of an object, we call it the object's *property of magnetism*, rather than *magnetic property*.

Comment: Will the great physicist please stand up? Cowards!

Comment: +1, not sure why there was a downvote...

Comment: Random, unexplained, down-votes are something of an ELU characteristic...

Comment: I would call them *chicken(s)*

Answer (score 0):

Magnetism has more than one property. Like poles repel, opposite poles attract, they point north, and so on. Collectively, these are magnetic properties.

You are correct that the thing is either magnetic or not, but magnetic and magnetic properties are not the same the thing. The properties (OED: *"An attribute, characteristic, or quality."*) are the result of being magnetic.